# Is Bootrap js and Material Design Lite js incompatible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design, material-design-lite

I am trying to implement bootstrap framework into my material design lite framework. Now, using bootstrap grid works good but when I tried using bootstrap collapsing panel it's not working. Is there a conflict between the js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap as your UI framework and want to implement material design, it's better you use [bootstrap material design theme](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design). This way the chances of conflicts are very less.

Material design lite is not intended for bootstrap and mixing those two will result in lots of conflicts (*mostly CSS, if not js*).

Comment: Yes, What I did is I used bootstrap and materialize css and it works no problem,